# Attaching metadata to Org link abbreviations?

Tags: org-mode, org-link

Is there some way to attach metadata to Org link abbreviations?  Something like:

```
#+LINK: Example https://example.com [metadata about link]
```

For example, date linked, a rating, a reason the link exists, other notes.

I can see I could add comments before/after the link:

```
# metadata about following link
#+LINK: Example https://example.com
```

And there's always the option to create a full BibTeX bibliography composed only of URL links.

Is an Org MACRO an option? The macro could just drop the non-link metadata?

```
#+LINK-MACRO: Example https://example.com [metadata]
```

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: How do you want to use the metadata?

Comment: Mainly for personal reference or reminders on why I recorded the link. 

In some documents using the links it would be good to be able to insert, e.g. a rating into a link reference.

Comment: So the only thing that matters is that there is a notation next to the definition of the link abbreviation? You don't care about structure or retrieving it in any way other than opening the file and reading it? If so, your comment idea looks fine to me. Org macros are only expanded on export, so I don't see how they could work.